# Problems finding absolute paths for DLLs using Python - pefile, win32api, win32con, wintypes, windll

Tags: python, portable-executable, absolute-path

This is part of a much larger, very complex effort, that I have cut down to just the essentials. I am using Python and the goal here is to enumerate all DLLs and to find absolute path for them, which i can then feed to pefile, to thereby load it.

What I have come up with partilaly works and partially does not. In some cases, it jut finds the address for Python.exe or is unable to find anything at all. Other times, it works perfectly. I am looking for ideas on how I can correctly find the absolute path for these dlls through this technique...or even doing something entirely different. Is there maybe something else that I need to import?

Here is what I have come up with:

```
import pefile
import win32api
import win32con
from ctypes import windll
from ctypes import wintypes
import sys
import os
peName= sys.argv[1] 
pe = pefile.PE(peName)
PE_DLLS = []

def getDLLs():
    global PE_DLLS
    for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
        print entry.dll
        PE_DLLS.append(entry.dll)

def extractDLL(dllName):

    # Part of this loadlibrary comes from: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/53932/ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
    print dllName
    try:
        dllHandle = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(dllName, 0, win32con.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
        windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
        windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR]
        windll.kernel32.GetModuleFileNameW.restype = wintypes.DWORD
        windll.kernel32.GetModuleFileNameW.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.DWORD]
        h_module_base = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(dllName)
        module_path = wintypes.create_unicode_buffer(255)
        windll.kernel32.GetModuleFileNameW(h_module_base, module_path, 255)
        pe = pefile.PE(module_path.value)
        win32api.FreeLibrary(dllHandle)

        print "\t*" + module_path.value

    except:
        print "\t*" + dllName + " could not be found."
        pass
i = 0
getDLLs()
for dll in PE_DLLS:
    extractDLL(PE_DLLS[i])
    i +=1
```

When I execute it with a file, such as as say IDA, I get the following:

```
USER32.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
ADVAPI32.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
WSOCK32.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
SHELL32.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
IDA.dll
        *IDA.dll could not be found.
Qt5PrintSupport.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
Qt5Widgets.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
Qt5Gui.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
Qt5Core.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
MSVCP140.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
ole32.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
KERNEL32.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
VCRUNTIME140.dll
        *C:\Python27\python.exe
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
        *C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
```

Observe the following problems: 1. Some came up as Python.exe; 2. some could find nothing (IDA); 3. for a number of similar DLLs at the end, it gave ucrtbase.dll. Any help on any of these would be appreciated, as I want it to be able to find ALL DLLs.

There is no particular reason why I am including IDA except that it gave three unique errors, and that was more than others I tested.

I have thought about searching the hard disk for a dll if not found, but that could run into issues with DLLs that are named the same. Additionally, an analyst could have something named as a common DLL but is actually a malware artifact, and that could be found just searching the hard disk. Finally, having to search could slow it down quite a bit. But I am open to any creative ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least two problems with your code:

1. Quoting the documentation for [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) and the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag:

> Therefore, you cannot call functions like GetModuleFileName,
>   GetModuleHandle or GetProcAddress

Your code has therefore an undefined behavior is is not guaranteed to work or return meaningful results.

2. You are trying to solve statically something that is done dynamically by the system. When the Windows' loader loads a module and then checks the IAT to find the imported modules, it then enters a quite complex mechanism called [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) which depends on the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) (emphasis on **Dynamic**).

Note that you'll probably also miss delay load import or simple calls to LoadLibrary from the program.

Your best bet would be to replicate exactly what the system does to get the exact same results.

Comment: It produces correct results for most of them. I have added extensively to search in SysWow64 or System32 if h_module_base is None (null), which was the cause of it getting Python.exe.